# How can I update Rally team membership?

Tags: c#, rally

I'm stumped on how to update team membership through the API. I'm able to add users to projects, through project permissions, but can't update the team membership to show that a user is part of a specific team. How is that best accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TeamMemberships collection on User is modifiable.  Since the question was tagged with C# here is an example of how to do this (assumes wsapi v2.0 and .net rest toolkit 2.0):

```
//Get the current team memberships for a user
var user = restApi.GetByReference("/user/12345", "TeamMemberships");
Request teamMemberRequest = new Request(user["TeamMemberships"]);
List<DynamicJsonObject> teams = new List<DynamicJsonObject>(restApi.Query(teamMemberRequest).Results.Cast<DynamicJsonObject>());

//Add the new team (project)        
DynamicJsonObject newTeam = new DynamicJsonObject();
newTeam["_ref"] = "/project/23456";
teams.Add(newTeam);

//Update the user
DynamicJsonObject toUpdate = new DynamicJsonObject();
toUpdate["TeamMemberships"] = teams;
restApi.Update(user["_ref"], toUpdate);
```

Comment: Your solution was similar to mine. I tried yours with the same result. I receive a warning back for the update operation. The warning states that it ignored JSON element user.Teammemberships during processing of the request. The Rally web services API doc indicates that team membership is a read-only field and hence my confusion. The places in the documentation that denote team membership are all labeled as read-only.

Comment: As of v2.0 it is writable.  Are you targeting a 1.x version?

Comment: Yes, the current version I'm using is 1.43

Comment: @KyleMorse can you briefly answer this in terms of Ruby?