# Rally updating Team Members to Project

Tags: rally

I have looked at "[How can I update Rally team membership?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993417/how-can-i-update-rally-team-membership)" but couldn't figure out how it works for Ruby Rally WSAPI. So this is my update query when I try to update team membership for a Project

```
#team is an array that consists of RallyAPI (user) objects.
@rally.update("project",project_ref,team)
```

My question is about the project_ref that I am passing as an identifier for the project to be updated, is it the "_ref" that we have to pass to this query or the "ObjectID" of the project, for the update query to work?

I get this error when I try

```
@rally.update("project",project["_ref"],team)

not authorized to perform action: invalid key
```

On trying this:

```
@rally.update("project","_ref|#{project["_ref"]}",team)
```

I get the same error. When I tried this query:

```
@rally.update("project","ObjectID|#{project["ObjectID"]}",use_array)
```

I get an error as "Could not find webservice for '...'using request method "POST", However a service does exist at the path using method "GET".

Comment: Solved it on my own, referred to the C# Link and got it solved.